# Deleted user still appears on system startup screen

Tags: macos, user-account

Recently, I had to setup a user for the Apple Hardware replacement team in my local Apple Store on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.2 called "apple".

After the repair, I deleted the user via Users & Groups in the system preferences.

However, when I boot the MacBook, the account still appears and seems to be able to unlock the disk (I use file vault). The user is not able to actually log in.

How do I get rid of this ghost account?

Comment: Could you check in the Console why the account refused to delete.

Comment: Actually the account did not refuse to delete. There was no error message and no significant information in any logs about any error. The account is not visible anywhere other than in the startup screen.

Comment: is it a hidden profile somwhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it thusly:

Open Terminal.

```
sudo fdesetup list
```

This will list usernames and uuids of the users FileVault knows about (warning: I'm unclear on the exact specifics of privileges granted by this file).

```
sudo fdesetup remove -uuid [bad UUID]
```

This will remove the erroneous user from the list.  For some reason I had to reboot the computer twice to see the desired behavior (i.e. the only person asked to log in on system start is me), but it works fine now.

If for some reason you need to figure out users' UUIDs (the usernames should be in that file, though my deleted user had (null) for a username),

```
dsmemberutil getuuid -U [username]
```

will give you their UUIDs.

Comment: I had to use the -extended option to find the ghost user I wanted to remove: sudo fdesetup list -extended

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here, I will file a big for that. 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4225458?tstart=0